# Find command with regular expressions

Tags: find, regex

I am practicing a `find` command and the moment, and am curious about the usage of regular expressions in the `find` command(similar to `grep`). Does the command support it? If so, what are the options to enable it?

I tried looking for it in the `man` pages but was unsuccessful so far.

Comment: A web search on _Ubuntu man find_ showed the first article was http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html  which you may find useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man find:`

```
-regex pattern
              File  name  matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
              on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match  a  file
              named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or
              `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'.  The regular  expressions  understood
              by  find  are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can
              be changed with the -regextype option.
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I saw that option, but being new to Linux, I don't understand if the regular expressions *here* should be used like in `grep` (ex. `^[a-z]*\.txt$`) or simply as in a shell(ex. `ls rando*m?text.txt`)

Comment: @Alex.Kh shell metacharacters are different from regular expressions - see the answer at [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119906/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver Oh Wow, that's actually a very nice answer about the difference between globs, regular expressions and extended regular expressions. I thought about asking something like that in the future, but I guess there's no need anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex.Kh if you want to dive even deeper, take a look at [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @steeldriver I will definitely look at the website. Just tell me please, does bash support everything that is mentioned there?

Comment: @Alex.Kh the bash shell itself supports POSIX regular expressions as described in `man 3 regex`, inside `[[ ... ]]` test brackets. I don't think *any* single tool supports *every* regex variant.